# placing an Order everyday automatically by an expert

Tags: mql4

i write an expert in mql4.and i want to place an order(BuyStop Order) everyday at exactly everyday opening.
i write the following codes but the expert does not work.please help me

```
// y means yesterday
double yHigh=iHigh(Symbol(),PERIOD_D1,1);
double yLow=iLow(Symbol(),PERIOD_D1,1);
double yOpen=iOpen(Symbol(),PERIOD_D1,1);
double yClose=iClose(Symbol(),PERIOD_D1,1);
double yRange=yHigh-yLow;
double P=NormalizeDouble(((yHigh+yLow+yClose)/3),5);

double R3=NormalizeDouble((P+yRange*1.000),5) ;
double R2=NormalizeDouble((P+yRange*0.618),5) ;
double R1=NormalizeDouble((P+yRange*0.382),5) ;

double S1=NormalizeDouble((P-yRange*0.382),5) ;
double S2=NormalizeDouble((P-yRange*0.618),5) ;
double S3=NormalizeDouble((P-yRange*1.000),5) ;

void OnTick()
  {
   if (iVolume(Symbol(),PERIOD_D1,0)<=1)
   int buyTicket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUYSTOP,0.01,P,3,S1,R1,"MyBuyPosition",7777,0,clrGreen);
  {

// P and R1 and S1 are pivot points and calculated at the top
```

this expert calculates daily Pivot points and place a buystop order at exactly starting the new day.(exactly at starting daily candle)

why this Expert does not work? :(

i tried more and more.but it does not work.i think there is a problem with line below:

`if (iVolume(Symbol(),PERIOD_D1,0)<=1)`

is there the other way to show starting new day instead of this code line??

Answer (score 0):

Using `iVolume` to determine a new day would be very unreliable. Instead simply use `iTime`. Try the following:

```
datetime currentDay;

void OnTick()
{
   if(currentDay!=iTime(NULL, PERIOD_D1,0))
   {
      int buyTicket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUYSTOP,0.01,P,3,S1,R1,"MyBuyPosition",7777,0,clrGreen);
      currentDay=iTime(NULL, PERIOD_D1, 0);
   }
}
```